# default="default" for option does not function

Tags: php, wordpress, rating, article

Adding the following script to the function.php file in Wordpress:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'rating_select_box' );
function rating_select_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'rating_select_box', // id, used as the html id att
        __( 'Select rating:' ), // meta box title, like "Page Attributes"
        'rating_select_cb', // callback function, spits out the content
        'post', // post type or page. We'll add this to posts only
        'side', // context (where on the screen
        'low' // priority, where should this go in the context?
    );

}

function rating_select_cb( $post )
{
    global $wpdb;
    $value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rating', true);
    echo '<div class="misc-pub-section misc-pub-section-last">
         <span id="timestamp">'
         . '<label>Select a rating:<br></label>';

         $selected = ($value == $result->post_name) ? ' selected="selected" ' : null;

         echo '<select name="rating">';
         echo '<option value="" default="default"> None... </option>';
         echo '<option value="0" '.$selected.'> G — Suitable for all audiences </option>';
         echo '<option value="1" '.$selected.'> PG — Possibly offensive, usually for audiences 13 and above </option>';
         echo '<option value="2" '.$selected.'> R — Intended for adult audiences above 17 </option>';
         echo '<option value="3" '.$selected.'> X — Even more mature than above </option>';
         echo '</select>';      

    echo '</span></div>';
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'save_metadata');

function save_metadata($postid)
{   
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return false;
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $postid ) ) return false;
    if( empty($postid) ) return false;


    if ( is_null($_REQUEST["rating"]) ) {
        delete_post_meta($postid, 'rating');
    } else {
        update_post_meta($postid, 'rating', $_REQUEST['rating']);
    }

}
```

Will add a box in the post page with a drop down list. I want the default option to be on `None...` so I added a `default="default"` to that option, but it does not work. By default, the highest number value is selected, in this case, it is `X — Even more mature than above`.

**What am I doing wrong**? How can I make it so that the `None...` option is selected by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a `select` list, the correct way to "select" an option is with `selected="selected"`, not `default="default"`. Changing your 'None' option to the following should fix it:

```
echo '<option value="" selected="selected"> None... </option>';
```

However, you're not dynamically creating your `select` list, you're just outputting a full list and you'll run into issues selecting the other values too. To fix this, if the options won't be changing, you can put them in an array to loop through them. You can modify your `rating_select_cb()` method with the following new code to achieve this:

```
function rating_select_cb( $post ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rating', true);
    echo '<div class="misc-pub-section misc-pub-section-last"><span id="timestamp"><label>Select a rating:<br></label>';

    // build an array of each available rating
    $ratings = array(
        1 => 'G — Suitable for all audiences',
        2 => 'PG — Possibly offensive, usually for audiences 13 and above',
        3 => 'R — Intended for adult audiences above 17',
        4 => 'X — Even more mature than above'
    );

    echo '<select name="rating">';
    echo '<option value=""' . ((($value == '') || !isset($ratings[$value])) ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . '> None... </option>';

    // output each rating as an option
    foreach ($ratings as $id => $text) {
        echo '<option value="' . $id . '"' . (($value == $id) ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . '">' . $text. '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';

    echo '</span></div>';
}
```

This method will *default*-select the "None" option if the selected `$value` is not in the available list of ratings. After that, it will loop through each rating and output it as an option. If the rating's `$id` matches the selected `$value`, it will be marked as selected.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on where exactly I would add this code example? If you could be kind to post it with the rest of my original code...

Comment: Thank you for the update, allow me a few minutes to test this code and see how it functions. Will report back very shortly

Comment: I just tested it and here are the results. By default, value 0 is selected which is **G — Suitable for all audiences**. Maybe there is a typo in your code? Do you have any clues as to why it is not working? EDIT: Maybe **None...** should be value 0?

Comment: @HenrikPetterson What is your default "value" if none is selected? It's possible that your default value is `0`, and in this case you would receive the specified issue. You can set the ratings-keys to whatever you want to try though.

Comment: Yes, the default value is 0. So is the solution to set None as value 0 in the option list?

Comment: I tested your very latest edit and received an error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: Error fixed (sorry, computer rebooted in middle of updating).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19096/discussion-between-newfurniturey-and-henrik-petterson)

Answer (score 2):

You should use it like this:

```
echo '<option value="" selected="selected"> None... </option>';
```

Comment: `<option value="" selected>` is also perfectly valid, as long as the doctype is not XHTML or XML.

Comment: doctype is XHTML here :) thank you for the respond, will test it and if it works, I will accept it as correct.

Comment: @ChrisSobolewski Issue, this worked, but the None option remains selected even if the user has already saved the post with a different option... making this solution impossible to use.